# Powershell copy file from domain server to workgroup shared folder

Tags: windows, powershell, server, permissions, share

Current situation:
We've got a domain with mostly Win Server 2022, including one database server. Next to that our backup server is in a different (accessible) VLAN, but did not join the domain (still in Workgroup). I've got a shared folder on our backup-server with permissions to Everyone.

Future situation:
I would love to write a powershell-script that automatically sends file from our Database-server (in domain) to our backup server (workgroup).

I keep struggling with permissions and auomatically putting them into the PowerShell scripting ... Anyone has got a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can authorize against the share with net-use first, then call your powershell

```
net use \\server\share /user:<domain\username> <password>
```

Or if you want to go powershell only, use the New-PSDrive cmdlet.

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\Server01\Public -Credential user\domain -Persist
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to put your password in the New-PSDrive cmdlet? It should become a fully automatic script.
I was maybe thinking about something like creating variables with username and password.

Comment: EDIT - Found it. Made use of the following:
$pass = "notsosecurepass" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('domain\user', $pass)
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\localip\share -Credential $cred -Persist